# ArgumentParser with optional argument (in a mutually_exclusive_group)

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, argparse

I'm trying to do a very simple thing - have only two options: `-p` and `-c`, mutually exclusive and may or may not have an *argument*, do `th...is` with optional argument or do `th...at` without one. This is what I got:

```
def main():

    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = '''ArgParser with optional argument''',
                                     argument_default = argparse.SUPPRESS)

    group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

    group1.add_argument('-p', '--project', dest='proj',
                        nargs='?', const='all', type=str,
                        help='list of project(s)')
    group1.add_argument('-c', '--component', dest='comp',
                        nargs='?', const='all', type=str,
                        help='list of Component(s)')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

    if args.proj:
        outString = 'project/'+args.proj if args.proj is not 'all' else 'projects'
    elif args.comp:
        outString = 'component/'+args.comp if args.comp is not 'all' else 'components'
    else: pass

    print('OutPutString: '+outString)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    try: sys.exit(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt: pass
    finally: print
```

which works just fine for the first condition in the `if-elif-else` block, so it works:

```
dass@mon105:~$ ./argParseOpts.py -p 
Namespace(proj='all')
OutPutString: projects
#
dass@mon105:~$ ./argParseOpts.py -p testing
Namespace(proj='testing')
OutPutString: project/testing
```

but not if `-c` is used instead of `-p` (i.e. the 2nd condition):

```
dass@mon105:~$ ./argParseOpts.py -c 
Namespace(comp='all')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./argParseOpts.py", line 32, in <module>
    try: sys.exit(main())
  File "./argParseOpts.py", line 21, in main
    if args.proj:
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'proj'
```

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing anything or doing anything fundamentally wrong? Using v2.7.2, if that matters. Cheers!!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: humm.... I see the same error on v2.7.3 as well. Trying to find out if I got v2.7.5 installed anywhere. But on the production machine, I have to use v2.7.2 anyway.

Comment: Sorry, that's what you get when I walk away in the middle of testing a fix for your issue, then forgetting I put it in. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Just added the `if __name__ == "__main__":` bit in the original post just to make sure that's not causing this issue. Juts tested on v3.3.3 and still the same error. Don't find a box with v2.7.5 installed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No attributes are set because you set the `argument_default` value to `argparse.SUPPRESS`, which means that attributes are never set unless they have an explicit value.

Set can set an explicit `default=None` value per argument to gain the attributes again for these specific options:

```
group1.add_argument('-p', '--project', dest='proj',
                    nargs='?', const='all', type=str,
                    help='list of project(s)', default=None)
group1.add_argument('-c', '--component', dest='comp',
                    nargs='?', const='all', type=str,
                    help='list of Component(s)', default=None)
```

and the `args.proj` and `args.comp` attributes will once more always be set. `None` is a false value, so the `if args.proj` test will not pass moving to the other branch, for example.

The alternative is to use `hasattr()` to see if the attribute is set:

```
if hasattr(args, 'proj'):
```

Comment: I think, the original issue still remains the same - it works for the 1st condition. With your fix, if I switch `if-elif` block, it fails for `-p` again.

Comment: @MacUsers: so add a `default=None` for the other option too.

Comment: `hasattr()` is the way to go to me. `default=None` is actually adding both of them to the Namespace, which may bring some other issues down the line in my original script. Thanks for that. cheers!!

Comment: Your per argument `default` is overriding the parser's `SUPPRESS` default.

Comment: @hpaulj: Indeed; made that a little more explicit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue is already answered using Argparse, I'd recommend using [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) as an alternative. Write the interface help message in standard form and thats all you need to do. If I understand your usage correctly it would be like so.

Also the key to fix your issue in this case is to make `-p` and `-c` flags and use a different variable `NAME` for the string.

```
"""Usage:
    myprog (-p [NAME] | -c [NAME])

Options:
    -p, --project        list of project(s)
    -c, --component      list of component(s)
"""
from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arguments = docopt(__doc__)
    print(arguments)

    name = 'all' if arguments['NAME'] is None else arguments['NAME']
    if arguments['--project']:
        ...
    elif arguments['--component']:
        ...
```

If we just print the arguments, the usage patterns will look something like this.

```
$ python myprog.py
Usage:
...

$ python myprog.py -p
{'--project': True,
 '--component': False,
 'NAME': None}

$ python myprog.py -c foo
{'--project': False,
 '--component': True,
 'NAME': 'foo'}

$ python myprog.py -p foo -c bar
Usage:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is the `SUPPRESS`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = '''ArgParser with optional argument''',
                                 argument_default = argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

With this option, if an argument does not appear in the `argv`, it does not appear in the `Namespace`.

```
dass@mon105:~$ ./argParseOpts.py -c 
Namespace(comp='all')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./argParseOpts.py", line 32, in <module>
    try: sys.exit(main())
  File "./argParseOpts.py", line 21, in main
    if args.proj:
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'proj'
```

When you gave it `-p`, `args.comp` would have returned the same error (except you checked `proj` first).

I like to test issues like this in an interactive shell (e.g. `IPython`).  There I can enter your `parser` definition, and issue commands like:

```
In [35]: parser.parse_args(['-p'])
Out[35]: Namespace(proj='all')

In [36]: parser.parse_args(['-c'])
Out[36]: Namespace(comp='all')

In [37]: parser.parse_args(['-c','test'])
Out[37]: Namespace(comp='test')
```

where it becomes obvious that only one of the attributes is set.